# start and pause buttons enabled/disabled swift

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, swift3

I am a beginner so I may not see obvious things at this point. So please, help. I need my startButton enabled again when pauseButton is pressed and vice versa. I cannot create a var that can be accessed by both `UIButton` functions though. What should I do? Here's part of my code:

```
@IBAction func Start(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    let disableMyStartButton = sender as? UIButton
    disableMyStartButton?.isEnabled = false

    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.update), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}


@IBAction func pauseTimer(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    timer.invalidate()

    WarningLabel.text = "Paused"
}
```

Comment: Do you mean to say, you can not take IBOutlet for two button variables? Why?

Comment: do you want to stop touch user interaction or change image while enable or disable ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create `Outlet` of your `buttons` and use them in your methods.

```
@IBOutlet var btnStart: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var btnPause: UIButton!

@IBAction func start(_ sender: UIButton) {

    sender.isEnabled = false
    btnPause.isEnabled = true
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.update), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

@IBAction func pauseTimer(_ sender: UIButton) {

    sender.isEnabled = false
    btnStart.isEnabled = true
    timer.invalidate()
    WarningLabel.text = "Paused"
}
```

You can also done this thing using single action for buttons like this.

```
@IBAction func onStartOrPause(_ sender: UIButton) {

    if (sender == btnStart) {
        sender.isEnabled = false
        btnPause.isEnabled = true
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.update), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }
    else {
        sender.isEnabled = false
        btnStart.isEnabled = true
        timer.invalidate()
        WarningLabel.text = "Paused"
    }
}
```

**Note:** You can also make same thing using single button by changing title or image of it in the action.

Comment: Thanks. However, there's "Cannot assign to property sender a let constant" error. Is there anything else that should be done to avoid it?

Comment: In the first solution with two actions at the line sender.isEnabled = false

Comment: @AntonPlatonov Don't understand why you are getting this error, have you replace your method with my one because i'm using `(_ sender: UIButton)` instead of `(_ sender: AnyObject)` that you are previously using.

Comment: That was the problem. Thank you. Now I have Thread 1: EXC BAD INSTRUCTION at the next line. But I'll try to figure it out myself. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @AntonPlatonov If you forgot to connect Outlet Buttons with Controller then connect it, may be that is the reason you are getting the crash.